# CLion and add_library(target INTERFACE)

Tags: cmake, clion

I have a header-only library project. In my CMakeLists.txt I use INTERFACE library type

I wanted to import this project into CLion, but when I open any of the header files the IDE complains that ***this file does not belong to any project target***

So is there a way to develop a header-only project in CLion?

Test project layout is pretty simple:

```
% tree foo
foo
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── foo.hpp
```

And CMakeLists content is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(foo)

add_library(foo INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(foo INTERFACE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_sources(foo INTERFACE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.hpp)
```

*CLion 2017.2 + CMake 3.8*

Comment: Using `target_sources` should solve the problem. I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by adding `target_sources`. I am using `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` which resolves to the location where the `CMakeLists.txt` is located. I then specify the location relative to that directory, something like: `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/foo.hpp`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after upgrading my CLion. You're very close but need to add one more line:

```
add_library(target INTERFACE)
target_sources(target INTERFACE ${my_header_list})
target_include_directories(target INTERFACE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

This may look different depending on your project layout. Mine looks like this:

```
|-- myLib
  |-- CMakeLists.txt
  |-- myLib
    |-- foo.hpp
    |-- bar.hpp
    |-- etc...
```

I got to this solution by reading [this](http://www.mariobadr.com/creating-a-header-only-library-with-cmake.html).

Comment: I have this "target_include_directories" line

Comment: Oh, sorry, you didn't mention that. Could you edit your question to put exactly what you have?